# MVC Projects upload on server and IIS6 without publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC project. I am not interesting a publishing my project. because after publishing it creates a single Dll. that times i am not able to change code of a particular page.

I want to direct upload a files or folders of MVC projects. Can It possible. if possibles, please explain me..

Regards,
Bharat Gupta

Comment: i am not clear what do you mean. but you can view your MVC project in your local server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. IIS is not a compiler and cannot compile your source files. It can, however, understand a DLL. When you publish your project, only the source code files (for example `.cs`) will be compiled and packed in the DLL. All other resources, such as scripts, images and even views, are shipped *as is*. You can only make changes within these files. This means that after publishing you **can** change your JavaScript code, or CSS styles or even "Razor code" inside your views (e.g. ".cshtml"), but you **cannot** change the code inside controllers.

Comment: ok thanku sir..

but i have a one more question. suppose a big project of MVC that contains many modules and many members of the projects. Each members are working on different different modules. after completed module. we are upload a projects after publish on server. but client changes code frequently. that is my question that case again publish a project and upload on server. In which process, code manage so difficult because project is big and many developers are working on same projects.

please give me a solution. how we can solve this problem.

Comment: @BharatGupta, Yeah, that's no light work. That happens all the time. The best way to go about this is to a have a version control system, where all the changes are made, and a build server, that builds the project. Depending on where the changes are made, you can decide to update just the files that are directly affected by the changes. You don't need to copy all the files to the production server. If you only change the views, just copy and replace the old ones. If you change the code in controllers or other classes, overwriting the project DLL will (most of the time) suffice.